# IntelliJ show references and same name tokens highlights on slider sidebar

Tags: intellij-idea

How to enable highlighting name references on side slider (place were lens is displayed)?

Example:

Warning, errors and some git markers are displayed on scrollbar slider as following:

[image]

Representing, respectively:

- errors
- warnings
- code additions
- line changes.

Is there a way to display same way currently highlighted function/field/variable/whatever token? Example would be:

[image]

Or

[image]

I wasn't using IntelliJ for a while and to be honest I'm confused does this feature disappeared, stopped working for me or it's just my imagination that it ever worked?

Comment: Ok, seems like a silly issue: I was using some non standard color theme that disabled this feature. To anyone how will ever need this:

Settings -> Color Scheme -> General -> Identifier under caret AND
Settings -> Color Scheme -> General -> Identifier under caret (write)
Check for both of them "Error Stripe Mark" on the right side of the menu :)